# Donations during the daily repetition of the Amidah; give one for the whole week?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, chazarat-hashatz

Someone goes around collecting donations in our shul daily during the repetition of the Shacharis Amidah. This is not ideal since it means that proper attention is not given to the  repetition. But it will not be changed.

It occurred to me that I could give six donations in one go at the beginning of the week to minimise the problem. But we know that it is better to give multiple small donations than one big one.

Do any of the sources deal with this potential conflict?

Comment: Is there a benefit to giving more small donations when it’s to the same person/place? Is there a benefit to give 100 pennies instead of 1 dollar bill?

Comment: If the person is collecting for himself you might be obligated to give him every time. Some people put money out at the beginning of davening for people to take without disturbing them.

Comment: Put a card out with your phone number for them to contact you after you finish praying to arrange to collect some change.